# Word for type of function that short-circuits a result until a specific call-gap has elapsed

Tags: javascript, function

I need a function `f` that when applied to function `g`, passes through the first call, then short-circuits subsequent calls until the time between subsequent calls is greater than a value.

In plain English: if calls to `f` come in like a "machine gun" I want a memoized value to be used, otherwise normal operation should occur.

Is there a word for this kind of function modifier?

```
var g = () => { /*...*/ };
var h = f(g); // is there an idiomatic term for function `f`
// `h` is now effectively limiting calls through to g
```

**Edit:**

Current hacked implementation (untested, doesn't support functions with parameters):

```js
function memoizeByRate(fn, options) {
 var lastCallTime = 0, result;
 return function() {
  var now = +Date.now(), tmpResult;
  if((now - lastCallTime) > options.lifetime) {
   tmpResult = fn.apply(this, arguments);
   if(options.test && options.test(tmpResult)) {
    lastCallTime = now; // !
    result = tmpResult;
   }
  }
  lastCallTime = now;
  return result;
 };
}

// "Test harness"
var i = 0;
var f = () => { console.log('call', ++i); }
var g = memoizeByRate(f, { lifetime: 1000 });

g()
g()
g()
setTimeout(g, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [*debouncing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debouncing), in your case with execution of the debounced function on the leading edge. However, that term is usually used for side-effectful functions only, so no result will be returned or even stored, you'll want to add the term [*memoisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) (as you already did). I guess I'd go for `debounceWithCache` or `memoiseInBursts`.

See [What does _.debounce do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15927371/1048572) and [Debouncing and Throttling Explained Through Examples](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In underscore.js terms, this is called [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle).

Comment: `debounce` postpones execution which is not what I am looking for. Reviewing `throttle`...

Comment: Can you confirm that `throttle` will avoid call through if configured with a minimum interval of 1000ms and calls come in at 900ms intervals? It is the rate and not the total elapsed time that interests me. In this scenario I want the first call to call through and subsequent calls to short-circuit.

Comment: @BenAston throttle will do at most one call to the original function every `wait` milliseconds. So if they come every 900ms, it will roughly pass through every other of them.

Comment: It looks like `throttle()` in such instances will execute the function every second call. It just prevents the function being called more often than the limiter.

Comment: OK, so on second thoughts I don't think `throttle` will achieve what I want.

Comment: Are you actually after an implementation of such a function? Your question is more general than that.

Comment: Ultimately I am looking for an implementation of such a function yes.

Comment: @BenAston: in this case, just take `throttle` and amend as you wish. It's _almost_ done :)

Comment: Currently can't see the trivial `throttle` modification you imply, but I will ponder it.